# Panel - Using the Enter key rather than a Button, for entering information

Tags: python, panel, chatgpt-api

Please note: The code is taken from the course "ChatGPT Prompt Engineering for Developers" by OpenAI and DeepLearning.AI.

---

My question is about the use of the library Panel, specifically how I can use the Enter key to enter information rather than using a button, the code appears below.

---

Please note that for the following code to work you will need to register and obtain an openai api_key.

To install the OpenAI Python library:

!pip install openai
The library needs to be configured with your account's secret key, which is available on the website: https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

You can either set it as the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable before using the library:

!export OPENAI_API_KEY='sk-...'
Or, set openai.api_key to its value:

import openai
openai.api_key = "sk-..."

---

However, the question is about the use of Panel, rather than about chatGPT.

The question is how I can use the Enter key to enter information rather than using a button.

---

The code is as follows:

```
import os
import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) # read local .env file

openai.api_key  = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

def get_completion_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=temperature, # this is the degree of randomness of the model's output
    )
    return response.choices[0].message["content"]

def collect_messages(_):
    prompt = inp.value_input
    inp.value = ''
    context.append({'role':'user', 'content':f"{prompt}"})
    response = get_completion_from_messages(context) 
    context.append({'role':'assistant', 'content':f"{response}"})
    panels.append(
        pn.Row('User:', pn.pane.Markdown(prompt, width=600)))
    panels.append(
        pn.Row('Assistant:', pn.pane.Markdown(response, width=600, style={'background-color': \
'#F6F6F6'})))

    return pn.Column(*panels)

import panel as pn  # GUI
pn.extension()

panels = [] # collect display 


context = [ {'role':'system', 'content':"""
You are OrderBot, an automated service to collect orders for a pizza 
restaurant. \
You first greet the customer, then collects the order, \
and then asks if it's a pickup or delivery. \
You wait to collect the entire order, then summarize it and check for a 
final \
time if the customer wants to add anything else. \
If it's a delivery, you ask for an address. \
Finally you collect the payment.\
Make sure to clarify all options, extras and sizes to uniquely \
identify the item from the menu.\
You respond in a short, very conversational friendly style. \
"""}]

# This is the relevant piece of code below.

inp = pn.widgets.TextInput(value="Hi", placeholder='Enter text here…')
button_conversation = pn.widgets.Button(name="Chat!")

interactive_conversation = pn.bind(collect_messages, button_conversation)

dashboard = pn.Column(
    inp,
    pn.Row(button_conversation),
    pn.panel(interactive_conversation, loading_indicator=True, height=300),
)

dashboard
`
```

---

I would like to know how it is possible to use the Enter key to enter information using the Panel library, instead of using a button, as appears in the code above.

Comment: This question is very strange. You go through an entire setup of chatGPT, ask a question about Panels, and Panels isn't even imported into your script. This is all over the place. You'd probably get help if you dump the completely unnecessary chatGPT part, and just make a little 3 or 4 line Panels example.

Comment: A search with the terms "Panels key bindings" reveals that key bindings were purposely left out in order to make it hard to create a key-logger. There is a work-around using ReactiveHTML.

Comment: @OysterShucker, thank you for your comments. I  have now added the required import to the code.